# Display subcategory in main category in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
  $cat = Category::all();

  $sub = Subcategory::all();

  return response(['cat' => $cat, 'sub' => $sub]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prepare your data to be easy to loop on it so you can get category with each related subcategory like this :-

```
$cat = Category::with('subCategory')->get();
```

so you need to add this relationship inside category model .
in this point you will get the categories with each category you will have its related sub category .